# Как сделать чтобы функция не срабатывала при нажатии на кнопки?

Tags: c#, ios, unity3d, arkit

**Суть вопроса:**
Есть функция которая срабатываетесли я нажимаю на экран. Как сделать чтобы она не срабатывала если я нажимаю на кнопки на экране?

**Подробнее:**
ARKit приложение для iPhone, изначально делается в Unity. Касаясь экрана я помещаю 3D объект на поверхность в этой точке. Как сделать так чтобы этого не происходило если я нажимаю на кнопки меню?

Решение проблемы из [этого](https://youtu.be/S7kKQZuOdlk?t=7m56s) урока почему-то не работает:

```
if ((touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began || touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved) && !EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject(0))
```

Почему этот вариант не работает, есть ли другие способы?

Код для помещения объекта на плоскость целиком:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;

namespace UnityEngine.XR.iOS
{
    public class UnityARHitTestExample : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public Transform m_HitTransform;


        bool HitTestWithResultType (ARPoint point, ARHitTestResultType resultTypes)
        {
            List<ARHitTestResult> hitResults = UnityARSessionNativeInterface.GetARSessionNativeInterface ().HitTest (point, resultTypes);
            if (hitResults.Count > 0) {
                foreach (var hitResult in hitResults) {
                    Debug.Log ("Got hit!");
                    m_HitTransform.position = UnityARMatrixOps.GetPosition (hitResult.worldTransform);
                    m_HitTransform.rotation = UnityARMatrixOps.GetRotation (hitResult.worldTransform);
                    Debug.Log (string.Format ("x:{0:0.######} y:{1:0.######} z:{2:0.######}", m_HitTransform.position.x, m_HitTransform.position.y, m_HitTransform.position.z));
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

        // Update is called once per frame
        void Update () {
            if (Input.touchCount > 0 && m_HitTransform != null)
            {
                var touch = Input.GetTouch(0);
                if ((touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began || touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved) && !EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject(0))
                {
                    transform.localPosition = Vector3.zero;
                    var screenPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToViewportPoint(touch.position);
                    ARPoint point = new ARPoint {
                        x = screenPosition.x,
                        y = screenPosition.y
                    };

                    // prioritize reults types
                    ARHitTestResultType[] resultTypes = {
                        ARHitTestResultType.ARHitTestResultTypeExistingPlaneUsingExtent, 
                        // if you want to use infinite planes use this:
                        //ARHitTestResultType.ARHitTestResultTypeExistingPlane,
                        ARHitTestResultType.ARHitTestResultTypeHorizontalPlane, 
                        ARHitTestResultType.ARHitTestResultTypeFeaturePoint
                    }; 

                    foreach (ARHitTestResultType resultType in resultTypes)
                    {
                        if (HitTestWithResultType (point, resultType))
                        {
                            return;
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (noShoesPlaced) {
                    UIController.GetComponent<ShoeUIController2>().showShoe1
                    noShoesPlaced = false;
                }
            }

            //if (placeFirstTime) {
            //  UIController.GetComponent<ShoeUIController> ().firstTimePlace = true;
            //  placeFirstTime = false;
        //  }

        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Если у вас **Canvas UI**, то нужно использовать **GraphicRaycaster**(*UnityEngine.UI,там функция raycast у нее первый аргумент EventSystems.PointerEventData там нужно заполнить position на экране*) и кидать им райкасты при получении **input**. Ловит все объекты у которых метка **raycastTarget=true**. Если вы используете **SpriteRenderer**, коллайдеры и райкаст, то этот самый райкаст вам и может сообщить.